# Why does Overleaf cap my pages and cut references?

Tags: bibtex, page-numbering, overleaf

I have a lot of references (over 100), but my list of references seems to cut off at 74. This is a list of packages that I'm using:

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
% \usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[figuresleft]{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newsavebox{\myimage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

And my end is:

```
% BibTeX users please use one of
\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}      % mathematics and physical sciences

\bibliography{reference}

\end{document}
```

And my `reference.bib` is 847 lines of `BibTex`.

What could be happening here?

Comment: the bib file is a database of _potential_ references. The generated bibliography consists of those entries that are referenced with `\cite`  (unless you use `\nocite{*}` to make an entry for each entry in the bib file

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) Sorry if you got the impression that Overleaf is capping your references for some reason. This is not something we do intentionally. Are you seeing more references listed when you use another TeX system, and the output is only capped on Overleaf? Have you cited more than 74 references in your text? As David has mentioned, generally only the entries you actually cite in the text will be printed in the output.

Comment: @PaulGessler - in my doc, I see references for MORE than the 74 listed. https://imgur.com/a/7p3XRKw

In these screenshots, you can see what I mean. I have a reference for 90, but that's not in the references list.

Comment: Hi Shamoon, OK, if you can't narrow this down to a small example code that shows the issue, you can send us your project URL to support@overleaf.com and we'll take a look at the whole project code.

Comment: @PaulGessler - done. Thank you so much. I'm sure you folks must be busy, but I'm trying to hit a deadline, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For future searchers: not mentioned in the code posted here was `\let\clearpage\relax` in the .tex file, which interfered with some internal definitions in the document class that relied on the standard definition of `\clearpage`.